# How can I pass input value in SOAP request from properties in SOAP UI tool?

Tags: unit-testing, wcf, soap, soapui

I am using SOAP ui to Test WCF services.

I want to pass value for input parameters (**ExternalReference**) dynamically from properties(Key-Value) available in SOAP UI tool.

Can any one know how to do ?

Sample XML

```
<soapenv:Body>
  <mer:GetDocumentSetList>
     <!--Optional:-->
     <mer:DocumentSetListIn>
        <mer1:SearchCriteria>



           <!--Optional:-->
           <mer1:ExternalReference>8B7A2F87-3546-456D-93EF-C8515BF4A14A</mer1:ExternalReference>

           <mer1:ListDateFrom>2020-02-24</mer1:ListDateFrom>
           <!--Optional:-->
           <mer1:ListDateTo>2020-02-25</mer1:ListDateTo>

        </mer1:SearchCriteria>
     </mer:DocumentSetListIn>
  </mer:GetDocumentSetList>
```

Comment: can you share the snapshot , properties are testcase properties,testsuite and project level properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very easy. in the Request XML you specify it like this:

```
<ns1:SomeParameter>${#Project#MyPropName}</ns1:SomeParameter>
```

Assuming that MyPropName is a Project-level property. If you want to use a test case level property, use

```
${#TestCase#MyPropName}
```