# How can I use a request parameter in the request body in SoapUI

Tags: soapui

The API I'm working with has a resource like this `http://example.com/api/resource/{id}`.  The POST request associated with that endpoint, also uses the `id` in the request body `{ "id": 0 }`

Is there a way in SoapUI that I can access the id parameter in the request body, so that I can pass the same value in both places?

Something like

```
{
  "id": ${parameter#id}
}
```

Comment: See if this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60433259/how-can-i-pass-input-value-in-soap-request-from-properties-in-soap-ui-tool/60446705#60446705 or this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58525954/how-can-i-make-requests-in-a-loop-in-soapui-with-different-content/58535311#58535311 helps you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Property Transfer, you can add following values to Target section in Property Transfer and pass value to 'id' in JSON request body;

[image]

To pass the same value to path parameter, you can add another property transfer in the same property transfer test step;

[image]